# MVC Identity validate user name and password along with custom property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity

I've added a custom property `IsDeleted` by deriving `IdentityUser`

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Currently I am trying to authenticate the user name and password provided by the user using the following code.

```
var userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<AppUserManager>();
AppUser user = userManager.Find(userDetails.UserName, userDetails.Password);
```

Assume here, I've created a user with user name "abc@xyz.com" and then deleted the user. When I deleted the user, the `IsDeleted` property will be set to 1.

Later, I created another or the same user with the same user name 'abc@xyz.com' and the later one is active in the system.

How could I ensure the `userManager.Find` will validate the active user and not the deleted one?

Comment: maybe validate for not having duplicates,base on other fields eg.email as it should not  be same for other  users?.just a thought

Comment: username is unique, you cannot have two rows with same username

Comment: @JephrenNaicker but assume if I am trying to create the same user

Comment: @NitinSawant  but assume if I am trying to create the same user

Answer (score 2):

You can do as follows:

```
 AppUser user =  userManager.Users.Where(u =>  u.UserName == userDetails.UserName && u.IsDeleted != 1)
                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

If you need to include password in checking then yo can do as follows:

```
var userHashedPassword =  new PasswordHasher().HashPassword(userDetails.Password);
AppUser user =  userManager.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == userDetails.UserName && 
            u.PasswordHash == userHashedPassword && u.IsDeleted != 1).FirstOrDefault();
```